# Defining IAM policy to reference params in another file

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I want to deploy a policy as a resource.

I want to reference resource properties from another file.

An example of how to do it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749424/passing-multiple-parameters-from-external-file-to-cloudformation-template-and-us)

resource.yml

```
Resources:
  MyGroupPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - iam:ChangePassword
              - iam:CreateLoginProfile
              - iam:DeleteLoginProfile
              - iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy
              - iam:GetAccountSummary
              - iam:GetLoginProfile
              - iam:UpdateLoginProfile
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: 
              - Ref: Param1
              - Ref: Param2
              - Ref: Param3
```

params.json

```
[
    {
        "ParameterKey": "Param1",
        "ParameterValue": "arn:aws:iam::7777777777:user/${aws:username}"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "Param2",
        "ParameterValue": "arn:aws:iam::7777777777:mfa/*"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "Param3",
        "ParameterValue": "arn:aws:iam::7777777:mfa/${aws:username}"
    }
]
```

command to deploy

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name stack --template-body file://resource.yml --parameters 

file://params.json --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

error

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Parameter values specified 

for a template which does not require them.
```

what am I doing wrong, can't I reference arn's from another file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `Parameters` section in your `resource.yml` template where you define what the stack should expect in terms of inputs. The template should actually look like this:

```
Parameters:
  Param1:
    Type: String
  Param2:
    Type: String
  Param3:
    Type: String
Resources:
  MyGroupPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - iam:ChangePassword
              - iam:CreateLoginProfile
              - iam:DeleteLoginProfile
              - iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy
              - iam:GetAccountSummary
              - iam:GetLoginProfile
              - iam:UpdateLoginProfile
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: 
              - Ref: Param1
              - Ref: Param2
              - Ref: Param3
```

Comment: not related to the topic, but could you point to some docs to store policies and resources in s3 and just pull em from there when I need to create stacks with resources that i create templates of? thanks for answering

Comment: I would strongly suggest you to instead have them in a source controlled project (ex: Git). This way it's easier to keep track of who modified them, view "diff" between versions etc. The next step after this is to setup a CI/CD pipeline to automatically deploy these templates when a new change is pushed into the source control.

Comment: interesting solution. how would you pull the secrets? say the user that would provision stacks with these templates would be able to know aliases. 
my use case was more like: build templates and keep them immutable. so, users would have read permissions. not write.